# Variable doesn't exist

Tags: php, variables

I have following problem. I have file variable.php with declared variable:

```
<?php
  $animal = "cat";
?>
```

And file b.php, where I want to use this variable in a function

```
<?php
  include_once 'a.php';

  function section()
  {
     $html = "<b>" . $animal "</b>";
     return $html;
  }
?>
```

and file c.php where I'm using my function `section()`

```
<?php
  require_once 'b.php';
  echo section();
?>
```

I have an error message, that `variable $animal does not exist in file b.php`. Why and what can I do here?

Best regards,
Dagna

Comment: You're misinterpreting the error.

Comment: Variable scope, $animal is global, and not in section()'s scope.

Comment: Can you post the exact error message, please?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

send `$animal;` to the function:

```
function section($animal)
  {
     $html = "<b>" . $animal "</b>";
     return $html;
  }
```

Comment: Generally, if you have to use `global`, you're doing it wrong.

Answer (score 8):

Variables have **function scope**. You did not declare the variable `$animal` *inside* your `section` function, so it's not available inside the `section` function.

Pass it into the function to make the value available there:

```
function section($animal) {
   $html = "<b>" . $animal "</b>";
   return $html;
}
```

---

```
require_once 'a.php';
require_once 'b.php';
echo section($animal);
```

Comment: Why is this not the accepted answer? By far the safest/most sensible approach.

Comment: I think this is not the accepted answer because it does not answer as literally the technical issue, it is however the best answer, and shows how better to solve this issue, and many similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
include_once 'a.php';
```

should be

```
include_once 'variable.php';
```

Comment: Wow, didn't even notice that, +1, although they still need to solve the scoping problem.

Answer (score 1):

One more alternative is to use classes, like:

```
class vars{
  public static $sAnimal = 'cat';
}
```

then in your functions, use that variable with:

```
public function section()
{
  return "<B>".vars::$sAnimal."</b>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it is meant to be a constant, you could use PHP's [define](http://php.net/manual/en/function.define.php) function.

a.php:

```
 <?php
    define("ANIMAL", "cat");
 ?>
```

b.php:

```
 <?php
    include_once 'a.php';
    function section() {
      $html = "<b>" . ANIMAL . "</b>";
      return $html;
    }
 ?>
```